# Heroku - disable SSL termination

Tags: heroku, ssl

I would like to renew, serve and negotiate SSL connections myself, within my application. Is this possible?

Currently it seems SSL connections are terminated on heroku's LB, and obviously I would need the raw SSL connection forwarded to my application's port to do this.

Comment: This forum skews more toward the main Salesforce platform. While some folks here do use Heroku, you might get more/better answers on [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Huh. Got here from the heroku support page. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible for just the reasons that you mentioned (443 terminating at the LB) - but I'm curious why you would want to handle this in-app? Seems like most of the solutions are covered - https://expeditedsecurity.com/heroku/how-to-choose-what-heroku-ssl-tls-option-to-use/

Comment: Thought I could get away with using my own certificates this way on a free dyno. I might wind up setting up a reverse proxy in front of it to be able to show "nice" url's.

Comment: Did you ever found if it is possible to disable Heroku TLS termination?.

Comment: I did not find a way. Using an nginx forward proxy as a workaround currently.